# Can small class choice be weaker than global choice and stronger than set choice + collection?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

In this [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351707/is-proper-class-choice-equivalent-to-global-choice/351711#351711) what was termed as "Proper Class Choice" principle turned to be equivalent to Global Choice over the base theory of "[MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory)-Foundation -Limitation of size + Set Replacement*". However if the restriction to relations with set domains was placed (as in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533971/is-set-sized-choice-over-proper-classes-weaker-than-global-choice/3534052?noredirect=1#comment7270161_3534052)), then it became equivalent to "set choice + collection" over the above base theory. This made me think of the following restriction:

**Axiom of Small Class Choice :**$$\forall \ relation \ R^{ |dom| < |V|} \exists F \subset R \ [F: dom(R) \to rng(R)]$$

In English: for every relation from a small class domain, there is a subclass of it that is a function from the same domain.

A class is said to be *small* if and only if it is strictly smaller in cardinality than the universe $V$ of all sets.

$^*$ *Set Replacement* is the assertion: "replacement classes from sets, are sets".

> Questions
>
> 1. Are there models of the "base theory + small class choice" in which there exist small proper classes?
> 2. If yes, is small class choice principle stronger than "choice over sets + collection" over the base theory? I mean are there models satisfying the base theory in which choice over sets + collection is satisfied but small class choice fails?